# GraphDb - Best practices to create a catalog of products

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, graphdb

I'm new to GraphDB and I'm trying to understand if it could be useful for my needs.

Scenario:
I want to have a catalogue of products of a specific type (for instance cars, watches, computers, etc). I want to have a database where I can search, sort, show related models etc.

Problem:
The products come from different sources (web mining, tabular data etc). Each brand has some "collections" and each collection has models and variations. Each brand uses different names for the characteristics of the model. So I can find a similar characteristic with a different name in my catalogue.

Question:
I tried to read the use cases and I found this (https://www.ontotext.com/knowledgehub/case-studies/edamam-mines-web-data/) that is similar to what I want to realize.

I'm trying to build an Ontology for my use case and I found it difficult to understand when I need to use a Class/Entity and when using a Relation.

What I figured out is:

```
Model A
      Part A
           Characteristic A
           Characteristic B

Model B
      Part B
            Characteristic C
```

In this case, what is the best approach to say that Characteristic A is the same as Characteristic C? A relation (`is the same as`)? Define another entity called Characteristic D that contains the two characteristics?

Am I following the right approach? Usually how you approach a business problem like this using GraphDB?

Thanks :)

Comment: `CharacteristicC owl:sameAs CharacteristicA` is the common practice in Semantic Web of you want to express that both represent the same real world entity. For classes it is `owl:equivalentClass` resp. `rdfs:subClassOf` in both directions

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that `owl:sameAs` is a good solution. By OWL semantics it merges (smushes) the two nodes, so you can't track their different provenance coming from different datasets.

If your classes have only a hierarchy but won't have specific properties, the easiest is to use the SKOS ontology and represent models, parts and characteristics as `skos:Concept`. You can have a different `skos:ConceptScheme` or `skos:Collection` per dataset, and then use `skos:exactMatch` to link characteristics.

In fact you can use `skos:exactMatch` to link nodes other than `skos:Concept`. Some Authority databases use this prop to link person/org records across national libraries.

For more help, contact us at info at ontotext.com. (I worked on EDAMAM 7-8 years ago).